# How to let user vertically resize window

Tags: c++, qt, resize, qt-creator

I want the user to be able to vertically resize the Window but I'm unsure how I would do this. I have selected my root object (View of type `QWidget`) in Qt Creator but I do not see an option to allow users to vertically resize the object. Does this have to be done through code?

Comment: check out QSizeGrip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if a `QWidget` is the top-level window you are able to resize it given that the `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` are different since they indicate the range of resizing.

If you want to let the user to resize vertically **only**, then you just have to set both `minimumWidth` and `maximumWidth` to the same value (probably to the current width of your `QWidget`). Qt will take care of indicating the underlying windows manager the rest.

You can do it in the Designer or programmatically using the [`setMinimumWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumWidth-prop) and [`setMaximumWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#maximumWidth-prop) methods. *Edit*: As mentioned in a comment, there is a [`setFixedWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth) method that simplifies this operation (and make it more explicit in your code).

Of course, you can play with the combinations such as setting a minimum width (or height, or both -minimum size-) to avoid your top-level window to collapse and become unusable, setting a maximum size... One common setting is making `minimumSize = maximumSize`, so you make the window fixed size (you can use the convenience method [`setFixedSize`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize)).

PS: see that this has nothing to do with the `sizePolicy`, which simply indicates parent layout which actions can be taken -regarding size- when placing the widget. As a top-level window has no parent layout this policy is simply not used.

Comment: There is also a convenience function [`QWidget::setFixedWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth).

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that, nice! Thanks @thuga!

Comment: I've just remember that if, in the Designer, you right-click on a `QWidget`, there is a _Size constrains_ submenu that help you with setting minimum or maximum sizes to the current one.